# Exportar Projeto com Imagens

Tags: java, eclipse

Então, eu fiz um jogo no Eclipse e estou tentando exportá-lo para um arquivo jar só que sem sucesso. A exportação funciona, mas as imagens não vão junto de jeito nenhum...
Aqui está um exemplo de como eu estou instanciando as imagens:

```
private Image imagem;
ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("caminho");
imagem = a.getImage();
```

Sim, as imagens estão dentro da pasta SRC.

[image]

Comment: As imagens estão dentro do projeto? Se não tiver, não vai importar junto mesmo.

Comment: Sim elas estão dentro da pasta src

Comment: Adiciona um print da hierarquia do seu projeto no eclipse na pergunta.

Comment: Perceba q a IDE nao reconhece a pasta como um pacote da aplicação, crie um pacote(package) e nova as fotos pra ele e tente compilar novamente o jar.

Comment: Mas as imagens estão dentro de um package (package imagens, aquilo não e uma pasta)

Comment: Olhe pra imagem q você postou e compare  pacote com outro. O eclipse destaca um package co. A cor marrom. Readicione o package, é bem provável que o  problema é o que já mencionei mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro pode estar relacionado em como você esta exportando o seu jar.Ou talvez em como você esta definindo o caminho até a sua imagem. Isso quer dizer que suas imagens estão sendo exportadas para o jar, mas não estão mais no caminho que você definiu em desenvolvimento.

Recentemente passei pelo mesmo problema. Veja como eu solucionei:

1 - Primeiro você cria uma pasta no diretório raiz do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Então você pode definir uma constante que guarda o caminho base do seu projeto.
Utilizando a variável System.getProperty("user.dir") você transfere para a jvm a responsabilidade de passar o caminho até o diretório do seu projeto. Independente se você esta em desenvolvimento ou produção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: user.dir vai retornar o caminho da pasta do usuario dele no sistema windows apenas. A intenção dele, pelo que entendi, é compilar as imagens junto com o jar, não busca-las na pasta do usuario.

Comment: user.dir = User working directory  
user.home = User home directory  

A vairavel que se refere a pasta do usuario é a "user.home".
Você pode consultar aqui.  

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: Sim, mas pelo que entendi, o objetivo é compilar o jar com as imagens, e o problema não é bem esse da resposta. Acredito que o ide não está reconhecendo a pasga img como um package do projeto, e sim como uma pasta externa.